# How to get the directory of main file

Tags: go

Let's suppose that `main.go` is located at `/a/b/c/`.

What I want to know is the directory where `main.go` is located, that is `/a/b/c` when I executed the file.

I've searched the Internet and tried many solutions but no one gave me the correct path.

The path should have nothing to do with pwd.

Below 4 examples should give same path, `/a/b/c`. How can I achieve it?

```
/a/b/c$ go run main.go
/a/b$ go run c/main.go
/a$ go run b/c/main.go
~$ go run a/b/c/main.go
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be when you compile the code, deploy the executable to some other machine, one that does not have the source code, and then execute it, should it print the source location on the developer's machine?

Comment: @mkopriva Hi, I just want to know the location where `main.go` is located. If `main.go` is located to some other machine in `/d/e/f` then I want to know `/d/e/f`.

Comment: Then you should probably embed that information manually before compilation because this is not supported out of the box, IIRC the compiler will, by default or with specific flags, strip the source information from the binary. i.e. once you run `go build/install` the info on main's location will be gone.

Comment: I think you can ignore my previous comment, it seems the only way to lose the file paths is to use a tool like `upx`. The `-ldflags="-w -s"` which I had in mind will actually strip away only the DWARF stuff, it seems.

Comment: @mkopriva Since I'm new to Go lang I don't understand completely what you mean. However I appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you want this information? Almost certainly, whatever you do with this information will break in the real world.

Comment: @Flimzy Hi. I want to store some data under a specific folder relative to not pwd but  `main.go`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. That simply won't work.  99% of the time, when you run your program. `main.go` isn't even around any more, since go is compiled, so your approach is fundamentally broken.  Instead, you should consider providing a config parameter to the program for where to find such data, or find it relative to the PWD, rather than relative to the source files, which are irrelevant to the running program.

Comment: @Flimzy Don't worry about it. It's just for internal test. However could you please give me the detailed explanation about `main.go isn't even around any more`? I need to know it for the future.

Comment: I'm not sure what kinds of details you want. Go is compiled. This means the source code is not typically around when you run it. You may have many (potentially thousands) of `.go` files that get compiled into a single executable. Only that executiable is distributed and executed normally.

Comment: @Flimzy Yup. At least to me It's Okay to get  the path of the executable file. Then I can create a folder on same level. This is what I want to do. Am I wrong?

Comment: Getting the path of the executable file makes _much_ more sense than getting the path of `main.go`. There are several questions here on SO on that topic, too, so you should be able to find one quickly.

Comment: @Flimzy I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path"
    "runtime"
)

func getDirectory() string {
    _, file, _, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if ok {
        return path.Dir(file)
    }

    return ""
}

func main() {
    address := getDirectory()
    fmt.Println(address)
}
```

Comment: I confirmed that it gives the correct answer when I used `go run main.go` or `./main` after executing `go build main.go` even when I changed pwd. Thanks.